# Redirect product from Quick.Cart to product in WooCommerce

Tags: .htaccess

I have an online store from the QuickCart which has 6 products.

The shop is installed on a subdomain (**shop.domain.com**).

I want to redirect each product from the "Quick Cart" to the specific product in WooCommerce.

WooCommerce store is installed in a folder "shop" (**domain.com/shop**).

Links to the products of QuickCart look like this:
(**shop.domain.com/?18,name**)

Links to products in the WooCommerce look like this:
(**domain.com/shop/?product=6**)

Please for your help!

Answer (score 1):

after much searching, I found the solution to the problem.
At this address I created the my necessary redirect:
https://websiteadvantage.com.au/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator#heading-ToolResult

Thenks!